# Display if statement setText in a JButton

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement, jbutton, settext

I am creating a game and I am trying to display an answer in a JButton using  the setText method. This is what I tried to do with the button

```
enter code here btnAnswer3 = new JButton(setQuestion);
```

This is the method I am trying to use

```
enter code here public void setQuestion()
{
    if (textAreaQuestion.equals("Which Prime Minister of England was from Huddersfield?")){
        btnAnswer3.setText("C. Harold Wilson");
    }   else{
        if (textAreaQuestion.equals("Where did Bruce Lee open his first Martial Arts School?")){
            btnAnswer3.setText("C. Seattle");
        } else{
            if (textAreaQuestion.equals("Who was the Prime Minister of England in 1940?")){
                btnAnswer3.setText("C. Winston Churchill");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me why this is not working and how it should  be done using my code.

Here is the code for the textAreaQuestion

```
enter code here textAreaQuestion = new JTextArea();
    textAreaQuestion.setEditable(false);
    questions.setViewportView(textAreaQuestion);
```

This is the code for the questions which is in a different class

```
enter code here private ArrayList<QuestionDetails> Questions = new ArrayList<QuestionDetails>();





public Questions()
{
    Questions.add(new QuestionDetails("Which Prime Minister of England was from Huddersfield?","Winston Churchill","Tony Blair","Harold Macmillon"));
    Questions.add(new QuestionDetails("Who was the Prime Minister of England in 1940?","John Kennedy","Harold Wilson","Harold Macmillon")); 
    Questions.add(new QuestionDetails("Where did Bruce Lee open his first Martial Arts School?","Baltimore","Hong Kong","Hollywood"));
}


public QuestionDetails generateResponse()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int index = r.nextInt(Questions.size());
    return Questions.get(index);
}
```

This is how it is displayed in the GUI class

```
enter code here displayQuestion();
    displayAnswer1();
    displayAnswer2();
    displayAnswer4();

    //This code will display the question and answers
}
```

This is the next part of the questions code in the GUI class

```
enter code here public void displayQuestion()
{
    QuestionDetails q = questHandler.generateResponse();
    String question = q.getQuestion();
    textAreaQuestion.setText(question);
    //This will display the array of questions

}
```

Regards,

Comment: is textAreaQuestion a string ?

Comment: What is the type of ``textAreaQuestion``?

Comment: It's been declared as private JTextArea textAreaQuestion;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it is not working is because an array has been used for  the answers. In this case the setText method will not be of any use.

```
Questions.add(new QuestionDetails("Which Prime Minister of England was from Huddersfield?","Winston Churchill","Tony Blair","Harold Macmillon"));
Questions.add(new QuestionDetails("Who was the Prime Minister of England in 1940?","John Kennedy","Harold Wilson","Harold Macmillon")); 
Questions.add(new QuestionDetails("Where did Bruce Lee open his first Martial Arts School?","Baltimore","Hong Kong","Hollywood"));}

public QuestionDetails generateResponse(){   Random r = new Random();
int index = r.nextInt(Questions.size());
return Questions.get(index);}
```

The way to fix this you would need to remove the answers from the  Array like this

```
enter code here Questions.add(new QuestionDetails("Which Prime Minister of England was from Huddersfield?"));
    Questions.add(new QuestionDetails("Who was the Prime Minister of England in 1940?")); 
    Questions.add(new QuestionDetails("Where did Bruce Lee open his first Martial Arts School?")); }
```

Then this method  would work effectively.

```
enter code here if (textAreaQuestion.getText().equals("Which Prime Minister of England was from Huddersfield?")){
                btnAnswer3.setText("C."+" Harold Wilson");
            }
                if (textAreaQuestion.getText().equals("Which Prime Minister of England was from Huddersfield?")){
                    btnAnswer1.setText("A."+" Tony Blair");
                }
                    if (textAreaQuestion.getText().equals("Which Prime Minister of England was from Huddersfield?")){
                        btnAnswer2.setText("B."+" Harold Wilson");
                    }
                        if (textAreaQuestion.getText().equals("Which Prime Minister of England was from Huddersfield?")){
                            btnAnswer4.setText("D."+" Harold Wilson");
                        }   else{
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case textAreaQuestion is the `JTextArea` you have to do `textAreaQuestion.getText()`

so:

```
if (textAreaQuestion.getText().equals("Which Prime Minister of England was from Huddersfield?"))
```

Comment: No sorry. It just leaves  the button empty

Comment: can you edit your question and post the code where you're setting `textAreaQuestion` ?